# What are the parameters that get updated through epochs in tensorforest algorithm?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, random-forest

Please I want  know the parameters that are optimized in tensorforest algorithm
When it comes to neural networks  we try  optimize the weights and bias but I don't know what is the case for tensorforest because I want to train the tensorforest in a distrbitued manner

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest

Each tree is composed of nodes and leafs. Each node is a threshold check on one of the features. Each leaf is a value computed based on statistics of the examples that reach it (based on the conditions of the ancestor nodes).

The final reply is a combination (I think it's average, but best to check the implementation) of the results obtained from evaluating the example against each tree in the forest.

Documentation says the forest is already trained in parallel, so distribution is already done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , the training is made  in parallel (multiprocessing) but I want know if I can use distributed tensorflow on a cluster of machines it will works the same way as  neural netowrks.

Comment: @AR795 I haven't tried it myself, but I would expect it would work out of the box. If you want to do it yourself, you can just instruct each machine to build a fraction(1/number of machines) of the trees then put them all together by averaging the results.

Comment: Thanks Sorin For your Help